# Text Spilling Out of Div

Tags: css, html

URL : http://66.7.212.201/~mobilegu/wp/

See the text "High School of the Dead OVA"

The last 2 words are spilling out of the div, how can I make the div longer so they fit?

Comment: I'm not seeing the text you are referring to.

Comment: Hit Control + F and search for: Highschool of the Dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can't.  This is a pretty common problem with CSS formatting.  It is also common when internationalizing a web app -- sudeenly all your nicely-tuned CSS are overflown by long German texts...

You either make the div taller, essentailly making it display two lines or more, or you "trim" the overflowing characters.

If you make the div taller, then you may be faced with too much white-space when most of your titles are short.

You can "trim" the overflowing characters by setting `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis` CSS styles.  (Note: `overflow:hidden` must be set, otherwise `text-overflow` is ignored.  And `text-overflow` is not support on all browsers).

When overflowing, some sites also do a popup (the title/alt attribute) with the full title upon hover.

Some sites have JavaScript connected to the mouseenter/leave events such that the div "expands" to show all the text when the mouse hovers on top, and then "contracts" back to one line when the mouse leaves.

You have to "plan" around this issue from the very beginning of designing your website.  Otherwise, even if most of your English titles are long enough to occupy two lines, suddenly when you have Japanese text in them, they'll overflow to three... or if you have Chinese text in them, all of them sudden fit on one line, and you'll have a blank space in each frame.

Comment: Sure.  Search SO or Google.  Answered another question exactly like this today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802205/does-html-support-clipping-label-for-width/5802262#5802262  I think you need something a bit different for FireFox.

Comment: Ok, so for the overflow and text-overflow styles, do I add them both to  " .thumb_section ul li .thumb_bg span "  ??

Comment: @Virendar, you add them to whatever div you want the effect.